# Create a new array based on an array of overlapping entities

Tags: php, arrays, algorithm, performance

Do you ever just have one of those days where your brain just doesn't get out of 1st gear?

I have an array containing start and end times. I'd like to create a new array showing the keys of the overlapping entries from the initial array. So, say we have some 'reservations'. Any overlapping 'reservations' belong to the same 'session'. An initial array like:

```
[reservations] => Array
    (
        [1125] => Array
            (
                [start] => 2011-01-07 10:00:00
                [end] => 2011-01-07 10:30:00
            )
        [1244] => Array
            (
                [start] => 2011-01-07 10:15:00
                [end] => 2011-01-07 11:30:00
             )
        [1311] => Array
            (
                [start] => 2011-01-07 11:00:00
                [end] => 2011-01-07 11:45:00
            )
        [1422] => Array
            (
                [start] => 2011-01-07 12:00:00
                [end] => 2011-01-07 12:30:00
             )
        [1561] => Array
            (
               [start] => 2011-01-07 12:30:00
               [end] => 2011-01-07 12:45:00
            )
        [1622] => Array
            (
               [start] => 2011-01-07 13:00:00
               [end] => 2011-01-07 13:45:00
            )
    )
```

would generate a new array like:

```
[sessions] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => 1125
                [1] => 1244
                [2] => 1311
            )
        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => 1422
                [1] => 1561
            )
        [2] => Array
            (
                [0] => 1622
            )
    )
```

What would be the most efficient way to do this for large arrays? Thanks!

Comment: I actually feel a little jealous that you have to have to solve this :) I'd say you should keep track of the start time and end time of each session, and for each reservation check to which session(s) it belongs. If it belongs to a session, update its start and/or end times. If not, create a new session. If it belongs to more than one session, merge the sessions. Happy coding!

Comment: *"Any overlapping 'reservations' belong to the same 'session'."* - this is not 100% clear. Do all the reservations have to overlap pairwise? Do 10:00-11:00, 10:30-11:30 and 11:15-12:00 form a session (the last one does not overlap with the first one)?

Comment: Thanks Rafal - I have ammended the example array to show that in this instance, yes, the three reservations above do in fact overlap as the first and last reservations intersect with the middle reservation. Equally, if a reservation were to end at 12:30, and another were to start at 12:30, they too can be considered as overlapping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For every reservation, put its (start,id) and (end,id) (separately) into an array of tuples sorted on first item (i.e. time.) Then go over the array from lowest time to highest, keeping what reservations are open, putting every new one in the same session. Once the last reservation in the session is closed, close the session.

Comment: Exactly the solution I was about to explain. ;-)

Comment: I've marked this as the answer as it's the closest to what we used!

Answer (score 0):

Not real code and thus not tested, but could be a way:

```
foreach([reservations] as $key => $res){
    $a[ timestamp_of( $res[start] ) ] = $key;
    $a[ timestamp_of( $res[end] ) ] = $key;
}

ksort($a, SORT_NUMERIC);  //sort by timestamp

$open = Array();   //currently 'open' reservations while looping through
$sesions = Array();    //result array for sessions
$active = 0;    //ID of active session

foreach($a as $item){
    if($item in $open) {    //check if current reservation is in list of open ones

        strip($item, $open);    //if so: close it → remove from array
        if( sizeof( $open ) == 0 ) $active++;   //if no reservations open, close the session

    } else {     //if current reservation is not open...

        $open[$item] = true;    //open it
        $sessions[$active][] = $item    //and add it to current session

    }
}
```

Comment: `ksort($a, SORT_NUMERIC)`. `asort` sorts by value preserving the key, while `ksort` sorts by key.